# How do i combine 3 regex patterns in JS replace() method on a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I've read a few suggested answers most seem to focus on the pipe OR operator, but i want to combine regexes. Shamefully newbie at regexes. Anyway, I want to remove special characters from tab, space and return. Here's what I have:

```
            var pattern1 = /(\\n)/g;
            var pattern2 = /(\\t)/g;
            var pattern3 = /(\\r)/g;

            $heading = $heading.replace(pattern1, "");
            $heading = $heading.replace(pattern2, "");
            $heading = $heading.replace(pattern3, "");
```

This works, however it is repeating and I can't find any info on how to create one regex pattern that will look for all and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them using logical ORs.

```
var pattern = /(\\t|\\n|\\r)/g;
$heading = $heading.replace(pattern1, "");
```

---

Using Wiktor Stribiżew approach, but for escaped special chars you could use`/\\[trn]/g` to match a backslash followed by any of the three characters.

Comment: \\<character> counts as two characters.

Comment: ok one can do it for escaped special chars with classes too (plus he asked for a solution not using OR).

Comment: Correct answer here.

Comment: @sjingo if this is the most helpful answer, click the hollow checkmark underneath the voting arrows. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the bar `|` to separate patterns with a logical OR. For your example, I would use the pattern

```
var pattern = /\r|\t|\n/g;
```

You can also use `pattern.source` to get the actual regex expression. That way, you can combine them at a later stage. Like this:

```
var pattern1 = /\r/;
var pattern2 = /\t/;
var combined = new RegExp(pattern1.source + '|' + pattern2.source);
combined.source
=> '\\r|\\t'
```

That pattern will match any carriage return, tab or newline in your test string. [See here for a working example](https://repl.it/CAga).

Also, check out https://regex101.com/#javascript. It's a great tool for figuring out regexes.